# How to check internet connection in dagger 2 module for okhttp3

Tags: android, module, dagger-2

I am creating module for okhttp3 using dagger 2. Now i want to check internet connection inside network module. What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Why would you want to perform that it module? What's the logics behind that?

Comment: I wanted to check internet connection for Okhttp3 cache. As i have created module of okhttp3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For those who are Following **MVVM** or **Kotlin Coroutines**(not necessary) and above **api 22** here it is:

With the new implementation of **Dagger Android** and **MVVM**.
Before deep dive into it your dagger class graph or object graph is already set, then you have to do something like:
 
**ConnectivityInterceptor Interface**

```
interface ConnectivityInterceptor : Interceptor
```

**ConnectivityInterceptorImpl**
You can use Custom Exception class or simply use **IOException**
*To Check the internet connection state of mobile device you've to use connectivity manager and of course enable network state from manifest as well*
In the **isOnline()** there are some of things which were daprecated for**api 28** or **api 29** and some method can't be usable if api level is below **22** so i used current state which not going to bother you either if you are above api **22**

```
class ConnectivityInterceptorImpl (
    private var application: Application
) : ConnectivityInterceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        if (!isOnline())
            throw NoConnectivityException() //custom Exception class
        return chain.proceed(chain.request())
    }

    private fun isOnline(): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager = application.getSystemService(
            Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE
        ) as ConnectivityManager
        var res = false
        connectivityManager.let {
            it.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)?.apply {
                res = when {
                    hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                    hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                    else -> false
                }
            }
        }
        return res
    }
}
```

**Dagger AppModule**
Here comes the Dagger Thing:
As we are using *Interceptor* for network state which is of course going to act as interceptor in the *okHttpClient* and Okkhttp is used here to make the network calls following by the *retrofitBuilder()* which means we are doing something called **Singleton**, so in that case we have to manage the object graph of Dagger

```
@Module
abstract class AppModule {

    @Module
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Singleton
        @Provides
        fun providesConnectivityInterceptorImpl(application: Application):
                ConnectivityInterceptorImpl {
            return ConnectivityInterceptorImpl(application)
        }

        @JvmStatic
        @Singleton
        @Provides
        fun getClient(connectivityInterceptorImpl: ConnectivityInterceptorImpl): ApiService {
            val requestInterceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
                val url = chain.request()
                    .url()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .addQueryParameter("api", KEY)
                    .build()

                val request =
                    chain
                        .request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .url(url)
                        .build()
                return@Interceptor chain.proceed(request)
            }

            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient
                .Builder()
                .addInterceptor(connectivityInterceptorImpl) // here it is
                .addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(ApiService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

**Enum Class**
To handle network State

```
enum class Status  {
    RUNNING,
    SUCCESS,
    FAILED
}

class NetworkState(val status: Status, val msg: String) {
    companion object {
        val LOADED: NetworkState = NetworkState(Status.SUCCESS,"Success")
        val LOADING: NetworkState = NetworkState(Status.RUNNING,"Running")
        val ERROR: NetworkState = NetworkState(Status.FAILED,"Failed")
    }
}
```

**Repository**
Do this in the Repository:
*if you are using DataSource layer, you can do that in dataSource class*

```
private val _networkState = MutableLiveData<NetworkState>()
    val returnNetworkState: LiveData<NetworkState>
        get() = _networkState
fun networkData(){
CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING)
            try {
               //Asynchronous Operation
               _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED)

            } catch (e: NoConnectivityException) { // custom exception class
                Log.d(TAG, "No Internet Is Available")
               _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.ERROR)

            }
        }   
     }
```

Inside your Activity/Fragment update your UI observing through *LiveData* accordingly.

```
myViewModel.returnNetworkState.observe(this, Observer {
          //textView or anything
        })
```

All Done.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at any of the [answers to this canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out) and simply encapsulate them.

For example, you could have an interface like this:

```
public interface OnlineChecker {
    boolean isOnline();
}
```

And then most upvoted implementation:

```
public class DefaultOnlineChecker implements OnlineChecker {

    private final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;

    public DefaultOnlineChecker(ConnectivityManager connectivityManager) {
        this.connectivityManager = connectivityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOnline() {
         NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
         return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
}
```

The second-most upvoted implementation:

```
public class ExperimentalOnlineChecker implements OnlineChecker {

    private final Runtime runtime;

    public ExperimentalOnlineChecker(Runtime runtime) {
        this.runtime = runtime;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOnline() {
        try {
            Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
            int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
            return (exitValue == 0);
        }
        catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in its own module or elsewhere just bind the implementation you want:

```
@Module
public class OnlineCheckerModule {

    @Provides
    public OnlineChecker onlineChecker() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        return new ExperimentalOnlineChecker(runtime);
    }
}
```

Now inside your Activity or Fragment you can simply inject using property injection:

```
@Inject OnlineChecker onlineChecker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super(savedInstanceState);
    //perform injection with Dagger 2 and then you can use your
    //OnlineChecker
}
```